# Woocommerce reminder push notification to flutter app

Tags: woocommerce

I have an e-commerce flutter app with woocommerce, i'm trying to schedule a reminder push notificacion for pick-up method for example:

when order has been received with pick-up method and delivery date for example 14/03/2022 at 03:00pm, I need to schedule a push notification on 14/03/2022 at 09:00am to reminder a specific user(in this case the user who create the order) "just to remind you that you have a pending delivery today at 03:00pm"

How can I schedule this kind of push notifications from woocommerce? thanks.

I tried firebase push notifications but i cant find the way to send notification to specific user.

Answer (score 0):

You should obtain users' FCM tokens during sign-in or anytime during the first app launch. When creating an order schedule a firebase notification with help of this Device token. You can make use of [Firebase Notification Scheduler](https://rapidapi.com/magno-labs-magno-labs-default/api/firebase-notification-scheduler/) to schedule notifications.